# Flutter: 'grpcpp/support/byte_buffer.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have yesterday remove my project from my Mac and clone again from the repo. After that have I a problem with building of my Flutter app in the iOS Simulator.

I received `fatal error: 'grpcpp/support/byte_buffer.h' file not found`.

So I search on Google and [tried this solution](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1941), but it doesn't works :-(

I don't know anymore what I should do, I hope that it's a little problem.

Please help me, thanks.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                            8,8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/capido/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/core/src/nanopb/writer.cc:17:
    /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/capido/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/core/src/nanopb/writer.h:28:10: fatal error: 'grpcpp/support/byte_buffer.h' file not found
    #include "grpcpp/support/byte_buffer.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: I get the same error, any solution?

Comment: I am encountering the same error. When I create a new user-account on my machine (macOS 11.2.3 / Big Sur) the error is gone with exactly the same project.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution that worked for me and which is probably a reason why creating a new user account in OS X worked for @BNetz.

The problem is that CocoaPods cache is somehow corrupted and everytime you execute `pod install` pods are fetched from this cache.

Easy way to clear the cache is to delete CocoaPods cache folder located here `$HOME/Library/Caches/CocoaPods`. This way you force CocoaPods to download correct version of pods by executing `pod install` in your project location.